# Graph editor showing errors

Tags: keyframes, error, graph-editor, fcurves

My graph editor is showing some channels marked as red, and I can't understand why.
Removing the keyframes for these channels will end up in changes on the animation, so I don't think the error is because the bone no longer exists.

This is causing me not to be able to import the model in Unity, as actions with errors will not be exported.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening here?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: So if you visit your Armature in Edit or Pose Mode, you can search for and find and select the "torso" bone in your Outliner?

Comment: @james_t Yes, it's there. rig->pose->MCH-torso.parent->torso

Comment: Perhaps you could share a blend file via "blend-exchange.com".  remove everything (character mesh, etc) in the file except for the Armature rig and the related animation.

Comment: @james_t I just found out that blender is somehow adding my armature keyframes in the wrong object. I only have my armature selected when I create the keyframes, but somehow they get associated with the wrong mesh object! Any idea why?

Comment: Perhaps you could share a blend file via "blend-exchange.com". remove everything (character mesh, etc) in the file except for the Armature rig and the related animation.